# MergeSort - Compiling but not giving any output

Tags: c, mergesort

This is based on the algorithm given in the Cormen's book. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void mergesort(int a[],int,int);
void merge(int a[],int,int,int);

int main()
{
   int i,num,a[50];

   printf("Enter the number of elements : ");
   scanf("%d",&num);

   for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
   {
      printf("\n%d) ",i);
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
   }

   mergesort(a,1,num);

   for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
   {
      printf("SoRTED ArrAy \n");
      printf("\n%d) ",a[i]);
   }

   getch();

   return 0;
}

void mergesort(int a[],int i, int k)
{
   int j;
   j=(i+k)/2;

   while(i<k)
   {
      mergesort(a,i,j);
      mergesort(a,j+1,k);
      merge(a,i,j,k);
   }
}

void merge(int a[],int p,int q,int r)
{
   int i,j,k,n1,n2;

   n1=q-p+1;
   n2=r-q;

   int l[n1],s[n2];

   for(i=1;i<=n1;i++)
   {
      l[i]=a[p+i-1];
   }

   for(j=1;i<=n2;j++)
   {
      s[j]=a[q+j];
   }

   l[n1+1]=1000;
   s[n2+1]=1000;

   i=1;
   j=1;

   for(k=p;k<=r;k++)
   {
      if(l[k]<s[k])
      {
         a[k]=l[i];
         i++;
      }
      else
      {
         a[k]=s[j];
         j++;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "no output"?

Comment: try running...  it just strucks after taking the input.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What input are you testing with? What do you think might be wrong? Have you tried stepping through the program with a debugger to see what happens? When you say "wrong output", (1) what are you getting, and (2) what are you expecting?

Comment: My input is just simple an array of 5 integers. I am expecting the array to be sorted in ascending order. But the answer im getting is pretty weird. for eg...  i input an array - 9,5,2,1,2. and output im getting is "Sorted array   1 9 3803680 2686368 1..  " all are in seprate lines..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void mergesort(int a[],int i, int k)
{
 int j;
 j=(i+k)/2;
 while(i<k)
 {
  mergesort(a,i,j);
  mergesort(a,j+1,k);
  merge(a,i,j,k);
 }
}
```

Nothing inside the `while` changes the value of `i` or `k`. So if `i<k`, the loop will repeat forever.

Comment: another problem... after changing " while" to "if"... its giving wrong output.. ps. i also corrected the L and R array size in declaration –

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is that `i` and `k` are never updated inside your while loop in the `mergesort` function, leading to an infinite loop. It's likely that you don't even need the while loop.

Comment: what change should i do in this program?

Comment: If you reread Cormen you'll see that the mergesort recursive calls are controlled by an if, not a while.

Comment: another problem...  after changing "
while" to "if"...  its giving wrong output..    ps. i also corrected the L and R array size in declaration